# file weight and how many lines in text file - how ? (C#)

Tags: c#

how to measure any file weight ?

and how to know how many rows in text file ?

thank's in advance

Comment: By file weight do you mean file size in bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long size = (new FileInfo(myFile)).Length;
int rows = File.ReadAllLines(myFile).Length; //for smaller files
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string filePath;
int fileSize;
int fileLines
```

**File Size**

```
fileSize = File.OpenRead(path).Length;
```

**Rows count**

```
fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
```

Or

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(path)) {
while (reader.ReadLine() != null) 
{ 
 lines++; 
}
```

Comment: whats the point of the `var` just curious why you would use it here, its not easier to read and is a bad habit in my opinion.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19568/can-we-stop-with-the-constant-overuse-of-var-on-so

Comment: i understand that, but `int` is just as long as `var` so it doesn't save space, it doesn't improve readability and it just confusing me as to whether `.Length` is a class or really is `int` . Just a pet peeve of mine that's all.

Comment: Reading through an entire file just to determine the total size is not such a hot idea.  You can use the `FileInfo` class for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a huge file and all you care about is the line count, you don't need to load it into memory, just use `StreamReader`.

```
long count = 0;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't line unnecessary? I mean, you could directly check `ReadLine()` against `Null`.